# Javascript Object Extension

Tags: javascript

I am working with Leaflet for a map on my site. I want to build the layer switcher dynamically. The constructor takes an object, with key being name of the layer to display on map and value being the layer object itself. I am building the switcher dynamically from an array returned by AJAX. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to get the value of an array object to be the key in my new object. My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: '...',
    data: { ... },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var overlayMaps = {};
        for (var i in data.elems) {
            var layer = new Layer (...);
            overlayMaps = $.extend ({}, overlayMaps, {data.elems[i].name : layer});
            map.addLayer (layer);
        }
        map.addControl (new L.Control.Layers (baseMaps, overlayMaps));
    }
});
```

My question is how to do line #9. `data.elems[i].name` doesn't want to work. I get this error `missing : after property id`, pointing right to the `.` after `data`. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't 'want to work'?  Does that mean that is doesn't have a value or what?  What do you see if you add data.elems[i] to your watch list in the debugger?

Comment: Object keys can **only** be strings. If you pass anything other than a string, it will be coerced to a string.

Comment: I mean I get this error `missing : after property id`, pointing right to the `.` after `data`. Sorry for not including that.

Comment: And that's my problem. How do I get the value to be a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just looking for [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation). Instead of this:

```
overlayMaps = $.extend ({}, overlayMaps, {data.elems[i].name, layer});
```

you want this:

```
var opts = {};
opts[data.elems[i].name] = layer;
overlayMaps = $.extend ({}, overlayMaps, opts);
```